# Outputting shell-command-edited buffer into a new buffer in Vim? E499: Empty file name for '%' or '#', only works with ":p:h"

Tags: vim

This thread [here](https://superuser.com/questions/157987/pipe-output-of-shell-command-into-a-new-buffer-in-vim) discuss about piping output of shell command into a new buffer in vim but it does not discuss it by using the current buffer like

```
 %new | r !%gcut -d '"' -f2,4,6,8,10
```

where the percentage sign `%` tries to use the current buffer, unfortunately resulting to

```
E499: Empty file name for '%' or '#', only works with ":p:h"
```

so

**How can I pipe the shell-command-edited buffer into a new buffer in Vim?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
:new | r !gcut -d '"' -f2,4,6,8,10 #
```

`#` is a placeholder for "the previous file".

If you have spaces in the filename, then use quotes

```
:new | r !gcut -d '"' -f2,4,6,8,10 "#"
```

Comment: What about if the filename you have loaded to the buffer has a space? I could work with with files having no space in their names but not with files having spaces in their names such has `notWorking\ hello.csv` while `yesWorks_Hello.csv` works. Is this a bug? Anyway this worked with files loaded to buffer having no space in their names +1

Comment: Well… use quotes.

Comment: And if you need to use a `#` literal (e.g if you want to filter out all comment lines with `grep -v` then you can escape it - `:new | r !grep -v '\#' #`